# How to force a union to behave as if there is only one type?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write a wrapper for the epoll Linux API. I forked [this](https://github.com/nathansizemore/epoll) repository, but this crate doesn't use the `union` type used by the `epoll` API. I decided to use Rust's C union feature to create a complete wrapper where user will not need to use unsafe code.

This union causes me some trouble.

How could I lock the used type of the union to one type at compile time?  epoll's union can't be differentiated; you can only use one member of the union by epoll fd. Well, you can but that will not be safe.

The user could use an enum type as the `ptr` field of the union to use multiple types but this will be safe because it will use Rust's `enum`.

I searched with "generic" or "macro" but I can't find any way that will fit my will.

```
extern crate libc;

#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
pub union Data {
    pub ptr: *mut libc::c_void,
    pub fd: std::os::unix::io::RawFd,
    pub u32: libc::uint32_t,
    pub u64: libc::uint64_t,
}

#[repr(C)]
#[repr(packed)]
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
pub struct Event {
    pub data: Data,
}

impl Event {
    fn new(data: Data) -> Event {
        Event { data: data }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let event = Event::new(Data {
        ptr: Box::into_raw(Box::new(42)) as *mut libc::c_void,
    });
    unsafe { Box::from_raw(event.data.ptr) };
}
```

I would like something like that:

```
fn main() {
    let event = event!(ptr, Box::new(42));
    let _ = event.ptr();
    let _ = event.fd(); // fails to compile; we can only use ptr
}
```

My fork can be found [here](https://github.com/Stargateur/epoll/tree/3c70ab3314246643822373986948135e54f12ef0). I don't know what macro, generic or other could be the suitable solution. You can look at my code, especially [the integration test](https://github.com/Stargateur/epoll/blob/3c70ab3314246643822373986948135e54f12ef0/src/lib.rs), there is a lot of unsafe code, I want to remove as much as possible of unsafe code from user side. Currently it looks very ugly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap the union in another type. That type will have a generic parameter of a specific trait. You can then implement specific sets of methods based on the concrete implementation.

In this case, we wrap the union `Data` in the type `Event`. `Event` has a generic type parameter for any type that implements `EventMode`. We implement specific methods for the concrete types `Event<Fd>` and `Event<Ptr>`:

```
extern crate libc;
use std::os::unix::io::RawFd;
use std::marker::PhantomData;

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
pub union Data {
    pub ptr: *mut libc::c_void,
    pub fd: RawFd,
}

trait EventMode {}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
struct Fd {
    _marker: PhantomData<RawFd>,
}
impl Fd {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Fd {
            _marker: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}
impl EventMode for Fd {}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
struct Ptr<T> {
    _marker: PhantomData<Box<T>>,
}
impl<T> Ptr<T> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Ptr {
            _marker: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}
impl<T> EventMode for Ptr<T> {}

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
pub struct Event<M> {
    pub data: Data,
    mode: M,
}

impl Event<Fd> {
    fn new_fd(fd: RawFd) -> Self {
        Event {
            data: Data { fd },
            mode: Fd::new(),
        }
    }

    fn fd(&self) -> RawFd {
        unsafe { self.data.fd }
    }
}

impl<T> Event<Ptr<T>> {
    fn new_ptr(t: T) -> Self {
    let ptr = Box::into_raw(Box::new(t)) as *mut _;
        Event {
            data: Data {
                ptr: ptr,
            },
            mode: Ptr::new(),
        }
    }

    fn ptr(&self) -> &T {
        unsafe { &*(self.data.ptr as *const T) }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let event = Event::new_ptr(42);
    println!("{}", event.ptr());
    // event.fd();
}
```

Attempting to call `event.fd()` gives the error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `fd` found for type `Event<Ptr<{integer}>>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:76:11
   |
76 |     event.fd();
   |           ^^
```

As a bonus, we can use the same `PhantomData` to encode what the concrete type of the pointer we have stashed in the union is and thus avoid mismatching it when we go to retrieve it.

Strictly speaking, the trait isn't *needed*, but I think it provides some nice built-in documentation.

See also:

- [Can a trait guarantee certain type properties such as a vector is non-empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47624992/155423)

Comment: I think it's exactly what I want.

Comment: Seems a little complicated. Why wouldn't you just have `struct Ptr(Data)` and `struct Fd(Data)` and put any shared behavior in a trait? I'm uncertain how this is used, so maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @trentcl I don't see any reason there can't be multiple answers :-)