# How to use Ruby mixins as patches to classes

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, mixins

I started looking into Ruby, since I am looking to a more dynamic alternative to Java.
I like how you can modify a class in Ruby after it's definition, for example like this:

```
class A
  def print
    "A"
  end
end

class B < A
  def print
    super + "B"
  end
end

class A
  alias_method :print_orig, :print
  def print
    print_orig + "+"
  end
end

puts B.new.print # A+B
```

Now I try to do the same with mixins:

```
class A
  def print
    "A"
  end
end

class B < A
  def print
    super + "B"
  end
end

module Plus
  alias_method :print_orig, :print
  def print
    print_orig + "+"
  end
end

A.extend(Plus) # variant 1
B.extend(Plus) # variant 2
class A # variant 3
  include Plus
end
class B # variant 4
  include Plus
end
puts B.new.print
```

However none of the variants produce the expected result. BTW, the expected result is the following: I want to be able to 'patch' class A with a mixin, in order to modify its behavior. I want to use mixins, since I want to 'patch' several classes with the same behavior.

Is it possible to do what I want? If yes, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your module code doesn't work because it is executed in wrong context. You need to execute it in context of `A`, but it is instead evaluated in context of `Plus`. This means, you need to change `self` from `Plus` to `A`.

Observe:

```
class A
  def print
    "A"
  end
end

class B < A
  def print
    super + "B"
  end
end

module Plus
  self # => Plus
  def self.included base
    self # => Plus
    base # => A
    base.class_eval do
      self # => A
      alias_method :print_orig, :print
      def print
        print_orig + "+"
      end
    end
  end
end

A.send :include, Plus
B.new.print # => "A+B"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't really use Mixins in this way. You're generating a conflict between the class and its mixin. [Mixins implicitly resolve the conflict by linearization.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925609/mixins-vs-traits) Bottom line is: In case of conflict, the class's method is preferred over the mixin. To fix that, you can use [Sergio' Tulentsev's approach and have the mixin change its base class aggressively](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10136408/52573).

Or, you can add methods reflectively. Consider this example, which I've stolen from [Mark's blog](http://www.vitarara.org/cms/ruby_metaprogamming_declaratively_adding_methods_to_a_class).

```
class Talker

  [:hello, :good_bye].each do |arg|
    method_name = ("say_" + arg.to_s).to_sym
    send :define_method, method_name do
      puts arg
    end
  end

end


t = Talker.new
t.say_hello
t.say_good_bye
```