# How to Solve Parallel Inheritance Hierarchies when we try to reuse code through inheritance

Tags: oop, inheritance, design-patterns, language-agnostic

Recently in a job interview, they ask me "**how to solve Parallel Inheritance Hierarchies when we try to reuse code through inheritance**". I thought on **Aggregation** or **Composition**, but i was a little confused on making an example based on that.

So I decided to leave it pending to deepen concepts later, but after investigating it did not end up forming a precise answer to that question, could someone explain me a solution or an example to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parallel Inheritance Hierarchies makes many unnecessary classes and makes code very fragile and tightly coupled.
For example, we have class `Sportsman` and its `Goal`'s.

```
public abstract class Sportsman
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public abstract string ShowGoal();
}
```

and concrete class `Footballer`:

```
public class Footballer : Sportsman
{
    public override string ShowGoal()
    {
        return new FootballerGoal().Get();
    }
}
```

and `Runner`:

```
public class Runner : Sportsman
{
    public override string ShowGoal()
    {
        return new RunnerGoal().Get();
    }
}
```

Then we have their goals:

```
public abstract class Goal
{
    public abstract string Get();
}
```

and its concrete classes:

```
public class FootballerGoal : Goal
{
    public override string Get()
    {
        return "Score 1 goal";
    }
}
```

And runner goal:

```
 public class RunnerGoal : Goal
{
    public override string Get()
    {
        return "Run 1 km";
    }
}
```

Now, it can be seen that if we add new type of sportsman, then we need add a new class to hierarchy of `Goal`.

We can try to avoid of creation of that hierarchy tree by using dependency injection and extracting method to interface.

At first, we create interface:

```
public interface IGoal
{
    string Visit(Sportsman sportsman);
}
```

and then just implement it:

```
public class FootballerGoal : IGoal
{
    public string Visit(Sportsman sportsman)
    {
        return "Score 1 goal";
    }
}
```

and use it in `Footballer` class:

```
public class Footballer : Sportsman
{
    public string ShowGoal(IGoal goal) 
    {
        return goal.Visit(this);
    }
}
```

Now we do not have hierarchy tree and we can call it like this:

```
new Footballer().GetGoal(new FootballerGoal())
```

**UPDATE:**

[There is a good article about Parallel Inheritance Hierarchies.](https://dzone.com/articles/code-smell-series-parallel-inheritance-hierchies). It proposes some ways to solve this task. Let me show the third way.

> Solution 3 Collapse a hierarchy.
>
> Pros:
>
> - Only maintain One hierarchy
> - Easy to maintain
>
> Cons
>
> - Breaks SRP fairly often.

So `Footballer` class would like this:

```
public class Footballer : Sportsman
{
    public override string ShowGoal()
    {
        return new FootballerGoal().Get();
    }
    
    public string GetGoal()
    {
        return "Score 1 goal";
    }
}
```

And `Runner` class would like this:

```
public class Runner : Sportsman
{
    public override string ShowGoal()
    {
        return new RunnerGoal().Get();
    }

    public string GetGoal()
    {
        return "Run 1 km";
    }
}
```

Comment: The final line of code still exhibits a parallel hierarchy. This doesn't seem to solve anything.

Comment: @jaco0646  could you elaborate, please, how it exhibits a parallel hierarchy?

Comment: He is right. You still have the same 4 classes. Which is fine, but your introduction of interfaces shuffles things around but changes nothing. At least not about the parallel hierarchies, you might have looser coupling, but I fail to see the point since it's always going to be the same two classes talking to each other anyways.

Answer (score 1):

The [c2 wiki](https://wiki.c2.com/?ParallelInheritanceHierarchies) has a page on parallel inheritance hierarchies where *ChaoKuoLin* lists four possible solutions. I paraphrase them here, along with some context for each. See the original page for a full explanation including advantages, disadvantages, and examples.

1. Keep the parallel hierarchies.

   - When the hierarchies have separate responsibilities and each contains many methods.
   - When maximum flexibility is required.
2. Keep one of the hierarchies and collapse the other into a class.

   - When one of the hierarchies can be reduced to a single class, for example by moving some methods to the other hierarchy.
   - When one of the hierarchies contains few methods.
3. Collapse the two hierarchies into one.

   - When the hierarchies have similar responsibilities and each contains few methods.
4. Keep a partial parallel hierarchy with the rest collapsed.

   - When you want a middle ground among the previous solutions.

Another solution suggested in the wiki is [Mix In](https://wiki.c2.com/?MixIn) and it is also suggested in [How to solve parallel Inheritance in UI case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31001443/how-to-solve-parallel-inheritance-in-ui-case)?