# Command Pattern vs. Visitor Pattern

Tags: design-patterns, command-pattern, visitor-pattern, mutability

Is it generally acceptable to allow a Visitor to modify state of the Receiver, or should that be a Command pattern instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The purpose of the visitor pattern is to allow new operations to be added to a class heirarchy without modification to that heirarchy.  I've never seen anyone suggesting that only read-only operations are acceptable.  The only limitation is that the added operations should only use the public interface of the class heirarchy.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can make a blanket statement whether it's good or bad to modify state of anything. I would think it's ok to modify the states as long as it does not affect the visiting logic itself. For example, you might write a visitor that visits all files under folder structure and renames the file name to upper case.

Comment: There are definitely cases where one can make the statement that changing the state is a good or bad thing. The Visitor pattern is expected to be used in such a way as a state change is possible and even likely.  Whereas with the observer pattern, the observer should not be changing the state.

Comment: what about an user, event for commenting, punisher listener which would ban user after saying some violent words? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft's example of a visitor modifying the receiver is the [ExpressionVisitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546136%28v=VS.90%29.aspx). The purpose of the ExpressionVisitor class is to modify an Expression tree. So I guess Microsoft at least thinks it's acceptable.

Comment: Microsoft isn't always the best guide as to what is right and wrong: http://ayende.com/blog/35841/review-microsoft-n-layer-app-sample-part-xndash-architecture-for-the-space-age

Comment: The standard interpretation when someone says "authority X thinks Y is acceptable" is that you are endorsing Y by appeal to authority X. cf. *argumentum ad verecundiam*.

Comment: @Jason Sure I'll consider Microsoft an authority. I'm saying here is one instance this authority finding this pattern acceptable. But am I saying they are the "best guide"? No . I leave it up to the asker to decide whether they're right.

Answer (score 1):

Each pattern has it's own pros, cons and use cases.

You can use  `Command` pattern to

1. *Decouple* the invoker & receiver of command
2. Implement *callback* mechanism
3. Implement *undo and redo* functionality
4. Maintain a *history of commands*

Use `Visitor` pattern in below scenarios:

1. *Similar operations have to be performed* on objects of different types grouped in a structure
2. You need to execute many distinct and unrelated operations. It separates *Operation* from   objects *Structure*
3. New Operations have to be added *without change in object structure*

Related posts:

[Using Command Design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015549/using-command-design-pattern/34789979#34789979)

[When should I use the Visitor Design Pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255214/when-should-i-use-the-visitor-design-pattern/35406737#35406737)