# stateful command pattern

Tags: java, php, oop, design-patterns, smalltalk

I was wondering what is the best way to represent an edit form in the context of domain model and I ended up with the command design pattern.

According to this: [Using Command Design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015549/using-command-design-pattern/2015971#2015971)
commands should be immutable which is not what I need - I need stateful command with editable parameters (the whole command will be edited in ui/form)

**Why is it considered to be bad to have stateful command?**

---

**EDIT**: After some time it is now clear I was looking for the ViewModel pattern. That is the appropriate way to model any webapp screen. Basically it is stateful (per view instance) controller.

Comment: Have you tried implementing mutable commands? Did you hit unsolvable problems in the process?

Comment: No - I'm going to implement it I'm just wondering if there are no gotchas...

Comment: @kamil, is this so you can do undo?

Comment: @hvgotcodes: command pattern does not really require undo() - although it is the common use of command pattern (as well as rpc call is - and that is what kicked me into this solution)

Comment: @kamil, my point was do you want to use the pattern so you can do undo?  If so, you are using the wrong pattern.  Use Mememto Pattern

Comment: @hvgotcodes I don't I just want to represent future action with all of its parameters, I want to edit them using form and then execute action by clicking the ok button...

Comment: That is a new command, generated by starting with a copy of an existing one.

Comment: The question lacks important information about invoker and receiver and a specific use case to have answers other than "it depends on the problem".

Answer (score 2):

You still want them to be immutable, because they can then be used to recreate the current state from a snapshot. But they can have all the parameters you want, as long as you make sure they cannot change after applying the command.

Answer (score 0):

if you want it mutable i would suggest using a FlyWeight Pattern instead.  You can make it similar to a command pattern since its a hash of objects and it reuses the same objects if they exist already thus persisting the objects state.

You can think of FlyWeight as a group of singleton objects you can call on the fly (by a hash function).

So a flyweightfactory would house all your objects in a hash map and you could use the factory to retrieve the object maintaining its state.

http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/flyweight-pattern.html   --> for anyone's reference.