# Command pattern use case?

Tags: design-patterns, command-pattern

What are some example use cases where the command pattern may be of use? I've been reading about it, and I have a good idea on how to implement it. But It's a big vague when it comes to knowing when to use it.

One of the problems it solves is to decouple the API of a class. But what does that imply exactly? What's the disadvantage of calling an object's methods directly?

What other problems does it solve, and how do they benefit from it?

Comment: Wikipedia has comprehensive coverage on the topic - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern. If you have to change the methods of an object, and those methods are called directly throughout a software project then the project has to be updated accordingly wherever these direct calls are made. It's a maintenance disadvantage. Decoupling prevents this type of maintenance overhead.

Comment: @ThisClark The wiki is one of the first places I went to, but most of the content (implementation, terminology, etc.) aren't very helpful except for the intro. As per the maintenance disadvantage, I don't quite understand. Could you give a concrete example please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why should I use the command design pattern while I can easily call required methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597736/why-should-i-use-the-command-design-pattern-while-i-can-easily-call-required-met)

Comment: @jaco0646 It does seem a bit misleading, but I meant to use that as an example. Furthermore, I was hoping someone could expand upon it. I realize there are others I may have missed.

Answer (score 3):

Command pattern is useful when you need to treat an action as an object, so that you can:

- add new action types withouth switch case construct (read: plugin)
- store the action to be exectute later (eg., active object)
- associate to the action complementary info (e.g., how to undo the action)

A simple example of command pattern in real code is the following.

When implementing a protocol, you can use the command pattern to decouple the parsing of a byte stream from the action associated to the message (remember that in OO you don't manage messages, but messages manage themselves :-)

When the channel receives some byte from the wire, it constructs the right command object (e.g., using the prototype or abstract factory pattern) and put it in a queue to be executed later (possibly in another thread).

Answer (score 0):

The **command pattern** can help you in terms of extensibility as you can add a new use cases without changing the existing code.

It also permits you to chain commands and execute it in sequential or parallel mode (dependings of the language capabilities) and create *macros*.

You can see more examples in this page: http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/command.html