# Simple Terminal Command Parser Design Issue

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, cmd

**BRIEF EXPLANATION.**

I am implementing a very simple command parser that requires me to handle a few commands:
`pw path`, `mv source destination`, `help`, and some others.
The commands always start with the `command name`, and then there are either 0, 1 or 2 strings after that. I do not exclude that the number of strings may change in the future, but the structure is always the same (as it is now).

I thought I could use the command pattern for this. Everything seems good in [my schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPEsY.png). However, when I attempted to implement it, I realized that there's a flaw.

I currently pass the necessary information to the constructors of each Command (each command has its own class as the design pattern suggests). For example, the `CdCommand` constructor takes the FileSystem and a `String Path`, the `MvCommand` takes the FileSystem and `String source, String dest`, while the `HelpCommand` only takes the FileSystem.
The issue is that I only know the inputs *after* I have called the constructors. That's because in my design I initialize the HashMap inside `CommandExecutionController` at the beginning of the program, by hardcoding the command names and passing in the correct command objects.

I could solve this by mandating that all Command classes have a `String...` parameter in their `execute()` method. But this would also force commands that don't require any string (such as the `help` command) to have this unneeded parameter.

I am looking for ways to mitigate this issue in practice. I've seen multiple times that the Command Pattern might be a fair solution for this, but haven't yet found any thread that explains what exactly could be done to solve the issue I'm experiencing.

Ideally I would want to follow this pattern and avoid `if-else` or `switches` (because they're not scalable), and especially avoid the `String...` parameter (because not all concrete command classes require it).

**ACTUAL CODE.**

`CommandExecutionController`:

```java
public class CommandExecutionController {
    private final HashMap<String, Class<? extends CommandInterface>> commandList;
    private final FileSystemModel fileSystemModel;

    public CommandExecutionController(final FileSystemModel fileSystemModel) {
        this.commandList = new HashMap<>();
        this.fileSystemModel = fileSystemModel;
    }

    public void register(final String commandName, Class<? extends CommandInterface> commandClass) {
        commandList.put(commandName, commandClass);
    }

    public CommandInterface getDispatchedCommand(final String commandName, final String... arguments)
            throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException
    {
        if (commandList.containsKey(commandName)) {
            Class<? extends CommandInterface> command = commandList.get(commandName);
            return command.getConstructor(FileSystemModel.class, String[].class).newInstance(fileSystemModel, arguments);
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Command NOT found: " + commandName);
    }
```

`CdCommand`:

```java
public class CdCommand implements CommandInterface {
    private final String path;
    private final FileSystemModel fileSystemModel;

    public CdCommand(final FileSystemModel fileSystemModel, final String... arguments) {
        this.path = arguments[0];
        this.fileSystemModel = fileSystemModel;
    }

    @Override
    public String execute() {
       return fileSystemModel.cd(path);
    }
}
```

How I'm currently calling it:

```
text = text.trim();
        final String[] commandParts = text.split("\\s+");
        final boolean isCommandCorrect = commandParts.length > 0 && checkCommandExistence(commandParts[0]);

        // Test dispatching
        if (commandParts.length > 0) {
            try {
                final CommandInterface command = commandExecutionController.getDispatchedCommand(commandParts[0],
                        String.join(" ", Arrays.copyOfRange(commandParts, 1, commandParts.length))
                );
                return command.execute();
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException | InstantiationException |
                     IllegalAccessException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
```

I've looked up other stack overflow threads regarding this question and the command pattern, but found no solutions for my current issue.

Comment: related: [What is the design pattern for processing command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54421/1371329)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am replying to my own thread since I found a "workaround".

First of all, I created a CommandsInfo annotation:

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface CommandInfo {
    String name();
    int totalArguments();
}
```

Next, I make sure that all my command classes are annotated with it. For example for `Cd`:

```java
@CommandInfo(name = "cd", totalArguments = 1)
public class CdCommand implements CommandInterface {
```

Now, I use the `Reflections` library. This lets me avoid having to register all the commands manually. Since I have all the necessary classes annotated, I just scan in the current Commands package, find all classes that implement the CommandInterface *and* are annotated with the `CommandInfo`. By doing this I can insert all the command classes with their relative command name in my HashMap. The idea is that all I need to add a new command is creating its class and annotate it.

```java
private void initializeAllCommands() {
        // Self notes
        // 1. Scan the current package to find all the classes that implement the CommandInterface AND are annotated with CommandInfo.
        final Package currentPackage = CommandExecutionController.class.getPackage();
        final Reflections reflections = new Reflections(currentPackage.getName());
        final Set<Class<?>> annotatedClasses = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(CommandInfo.class);

        for (Class<?> annotatedClass : annotatedClasses) {
            // 2. Check if the current class implements the CommandInterface.
            if (CommandInterface.class.isAssignableFrom(annotatedClass)) {
                // 3. Check if there is the CommandInfo annotation for the current command class.
                final CommandInfo annotation = annotatedClass.getAnnotation(CommandInfo.class);
                if (annotation != null) {
                    commandList.put(annotation.name(), annotatedClass.asSubclass(CommandInterface.class));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Next, I call the dispatcher by passing the command name retrieved from the user input and the rest of the arguments.

```java
 try {
            final CommandInterface command = commandExecutionController.getDispatchedCommand(commandParts[0],
                    Arrays.copyOfRange(commandParts, 1, commandParts.length));
            return command.execute();
        }
```

Next, all we need is to verify the syntax of the command. This becomes easier because all the classes are annotated with command name + the number of arguments that it takes:

```java
if (commandList.containsKey(commandName)) {
            final Class<? extends CommandInterface> genericCommand = commandList.get(commandName);
            final CommandInfo annotation = genericCommand.getAnnotation(CommandInfo.class);

            if (annotation.totalArguments() != arguments.length) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong number of arguments for command: " + commandName
                + " [Expected: " + annotation.totalArguments() + ", provided: " + arguments.length + "]");
            }

return genericCommand.getConstructor(FileSystemModel.class, String[].class)
                    .newInstance(fileSystemModel, arguments);
```

And finally, each command constructor can still keep the `String...` parameter. Since at the point of constructor we know that the syntax is correct, we can just do something like this as an example:

```java
public MvCommand(final FileSystemModel receiver, final String... arguments) {
        this.receiver = receiver;
        this.origin = arguments[0];
        this.destination = arguments[1];
    }
```

If we have a command that requires no argument, we can just avoid the `String...` parameter whatsoever.

This seems to work fine. It might be overengineered, but hey...

(I would also like to thank vanOekel for their answer, by the way. I've read it too late!!)

Answer (score 0):

The command pattern has a couple of [uses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597736/why-should-i-use-the-command-design-pattern-while-i-can-easily-call-required-met) but not for a simple terminal command parser as far as I can see. You could consider using one of the many command line parsers [available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367706/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-java).

I do agree that the `execute()` command should have no parameters - an important point of the pattern is the decoupling of the command object from other objects. Parameters would introduce coupling.

One approach to solve the issue is to look at the [wizards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) use-case for the command-line pattern. Instead of assuming everything is available from the beginning, build the command object until it is ready to execute.

First, I want to point out that the `commandList` is a hidden `switch` statement. Unless you are sure you are going to need this map (in combination with reflection via `getContructor` etc.), I would not shy away from using a `switch`. See also [YAGNI](https://xkcd.com/974/).

The `getDispatchedCommand` can be limited to getting the appropriate command:

```java
CommandInterface getDispatchedCommand(String command) {
  switch (command) {
    "cp": return new CpCommand();
    // etc.
}
```

`CpCommand` can implement `FileSystemCommandInterface` to set appropriate command values:

```java
FileSystemCommandInterface extends CommandInterface {
  void setFileSystemModel(FileSystemModel fileSystemModel);
  void setCommandArguments(String... args);
}
```

A simple `instanceof` can determine if the returned command object needs the additional values. The help-command can simply only implement `CommandInterface` which does not require a `FileSystemModel` or `CommandArguments` (the latter you indicated, the first I assume). Note, however, that `help mv` could be implemented to give detailed information about the `mv` command (this is a common "help" command line pattern).

This is the gist of my idea, where exactly which code goes I'll leave up to you and what you think fits best with the command pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your insights. I have found a "different solution" that I will post just for future reference. Not too sure whether it's optimal, but it works seemingly well for me.