# java command pattern example with Runnable class : Is Receiver missing?

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns, runnable, command-pattern

From [Examples of GoF Design Patterns in Java's core libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns-in-javas-core-libraries/2707195#2707195) question, it was quoted that

> All implementations of java.lang.Runnable are examples of **Command** pattern.

As per my understanding of Command pattern,

***Client*** calls **Invoker** => **Invoker** calls **ConcreteCommand** => **ConcreteCommand** calls **Receiver** method, which implements abstract **Command** method.

Have a look at this working [example](https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-command)

Command pattern UML diagram from [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/106198/Design-Patterns-nuff-said) is shown as below.

[image]

Have a look at this code:

```
public class ThreadCommand{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Thread t = new Thread(new MyRunnable());
        t.start();
    }
}
class MyRunnable implements Runnable{
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Running:"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}
```

1. *ThreadCommand* is **Client**
2. *Runnable* interface is **Command**
3. *MyRunnable* is **ConcreteCommmand**
4. *Thread* is **Invoker** with `start()` method calling **ConcreteCommand** implementaiton ( which calls `run()` method)

***Is Receiver missing here? Or Does MyRunnable play combined role of ConcreteCommand and Receiver***?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *Receiver* is optional, depending on whether the *ConcreteCommmand* owns the business logic to be executed. From page 238 of the book,

> A command can have a wide range of abilities. At one extreme it merely defines a binding between a receiver and the actions that carry out the request. At the other extreme it implements everything itself without delegating to a receiver at all.

In the original question we see an example with no receiver, because `MyRunnable` owns the logic to be executed. In two other answers here we see examples delegating to explicit receivers named `Receiver` and `Account`.

Comment: The *receiver* object is the type that represents the business logic of an application. The responsibility of a command is not to own the business logic, but to expose this business logic to clients using a common and standard interface, i.e. the `execute` method. Then, I think that the receiver is not merely a relic of C/C++.

Comment: I think you are partially correct. I have revised my answer.

Answer (score 4):

One answer has been posted here and it was removed by author immediately. While reading the answer, I have found solution.

I can simply convert above example to Command pattern UML diagram with one small change.

***I can pass Receiver object to MyRunnable ( ConcreteCommand )***.

Now I have changed my code as below.

```
public class ThreadCommand{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Receiver r = new AC();
        Thread t = new Thread(new MyRunnable(r));
        t.start();
    }
}
class MyRunnable implements Runnable{
    private Receiver receiver;
    public MyRunnable(Receiver r){
        this.receiver = r;
    }
    public void run(){
        receiver.execute();
    }
}
interface Receiver{
    public void execute();
}
class AC implements Receiver{
    public void execute(){
        System.out.println("I am AC");
    }
}
class Fan implements Receiver{
    public void execute(){
        System.out.println("I am Fan");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
 java ThreadCommand
 I am AC
```

Comment: And don't you know where is the Reciever in javax.swing.Action? (As I undestand it's actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) method among others really implements Command)

Answer (score 2):

I wanna give my two cents...

The original Command pattern separates the `Command` objects from the `Receiver` objects because the responsibility of the two sets are different.

`Receiver`s own the *business logic* of the application. These types should exist outside the pattern. In a practical case, `Receiver`s were probably already present in the code base, before commands.

For example, thinking to a *bank* application, a receiver can be represented by the following type:

```
public class Account {
    private final double balance;
    // Construct omissis
    public Account deposit(double amount) {
        // Deposit code
    }
    public Account withdraw(double amount) {
        // Withdraw code
    }
}
```

One of the aims of the *command design pattern* is that of give a unified, homogeneous  and standard way to execute operations on a set of objects (i.e. the receivers). They have not to care how to perform the real business logic. This will **limit the reusability** of the code implementing business logic.

For this reason, the `Command`s implementation has to forward the information to the `Receiver`. It follows an example.

```
public class DepositCommand implements Command {
    private final Account account;
    // An instance of Command should reprenset only a single request
    private final double amount;
    public DepositCommand(Account account, double amount) {
        this.account = account;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public void execute() {
        account.deposit(amount);
    }

    // Omissis..
}
```

In conclusion, imho, the statement in the accepted answer is not correct.

> The receiver is a relic of C/C++ in which the method to be invoked is separated from the object to invoke it on.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't receiver be...

```
System.out.println("Running:"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

call in the run method. Because that is receiving the action to do when the Runnable runs.