# Are my classes examples of "Command" and "Dispatcher" patterns?

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

My Android application is concerned with communicating with another hardware device over a Bluetooth or USB connection. To communicate with that hardware device, it uses a command-response protocol. Each kind of command type has its own expected length of response, time-out value, what has got to be done with the response that comes back, and other parameters that are unique to each kind of command.

I decided to encapsulate everything about each type of command into a `Command` object, which is subclassed by each kind of `Command` to create concrete implementations. These objects have methods that are called to provide the initial command (series of bytes), a method to call with the response that comes back, and so on. For me this is elegant because everything about a particular command to the external hardware device, from what to send initially to how to process the response, what to do on errors, etc. is all encapsulated in a class.

Is this an example of "command pattern"?

Secondly, I have a class that is concerned with holding such `Command` objects in a queue and sequentially executing them (that is, sending out their command bytes via Bluetooth / USB, and calling methods on that `Command` to handle the response, errors, and so forth). Is there any particular pattern name for this, and what would be the best kind of class name? Perhaps `CommandExecutor`, `CommandDispatcher`?

Comment: [Yes/no questions about an example are not a good fit for this site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258630/where-is-the-line-for-yes-no-questions). Answers to such questions are rarely useful to anyone except the original asker. The purpose of this site is to create a useful repository of high quality questions with answers. Instead of asking "is this an example of _X_", ask "what is _X_". What makes you think your code **might not** be an example of the Command and Dispatcher patterns?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Command Design pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015549/using-command-design-pattern)

Comment: I take your point, but I'm perfectly aware of the purpose of the site. I shall not be spending time attempting to refactor the question, so vote to close as you see fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this sounds like a standard implementation of the Command Pattern.
The pattern is described e.g. in the book [Design Patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gang_of_Four_%28software%29) by the "Gang of Four". If you have no hardcopy at hand, you can find it online e.g. on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) or [Blackwasp](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/Command.aspx).

Your `CommandExecutor`/`CommandDispatcher` seem to be `Invoker`s in the Pattern terminology. How the Invoker consumes the Commands is an implementation detail, a FIFO queue is just one way. So there is no specific name for this. But you could use another Design Pattern for this, if it matches your needs, e.g. a scheduler with or without parallel execution of the commands (see also [Active Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_object)).

*Hint:*
If you take a look at the Pattern explanations, you will see that you have merged the `Receiver`s and `Command`s into one class, since your Commands know the business logic to execute (=sending bytes, process response, etc.). So you can improve your design if you put this business logic into specific `Receiver` classes, which are used by the Commands. This way the Command Pattern is just a layer which uses the Receivers/business logic. This enables better testing of the business logic without taking care of the Commands as well as makes the Command Pattern exchangeable.