# How to create a HashMap with methods as values?

Tags: java, oop, hashmap

I am working a small program which can receive several commands. Each of these commands should cause different methods to run. I was thinking that if there were a way to put all the methods into a HashMap and invoke them directly by getting the value paired with the command Key instead of using if statements, it could make things much simpler but as far as I understand this is not possible since methods aren't treated as objects in Java. Still, it will be educative to find out if there is a way to do this.

Comment: You've described the "Command Design Pattern" pretty well. Look it up and consider implementing it.

Comment: Have a look at this Q/A for more on this: [Using Command Design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015549/using-command-design-pattern)

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter I don't see how this answers my initial question about putting methods into HashMaps but that might just be my relative illiteracy in Java since I only started a few weeks ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Methods* aren't objects (at least mostly not), but there is a concept that matches what you want: the *functional interface*, which is defined as an interface that has exactly one abstract method. Two out-of-the-box candidates are [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html), which takes no parameters, and [`Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html), which takes a single parameter and might be the best option if you want to pass in some kind of input (like a `Scanner`). (If you also want a configurable output, `BiConsumer` taking a `Scanner` and a `PrintWriter` might be suitable.)

Java has a convenience feature called *method references* that can automatically transform a method into an instance of a functional interface. Put together, it might look like this:

```
Map<String, Consumer<Scanner>> commands = new HashMap<>();
...
commands.put("foo", someCommand::go); // where someCommand is a variable with a go(Scanner) method
commands.put("bar", new OtherCommand());
commands.put("hello", unused -> { System.out.println("Hello!"); });
...
String commandName = scanner.next();
commands.get(commandName).accept(scanner);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good idea, make methods as hashmap value don't satisfied shell command complex scene, maybe you can use Runnable Object as value.

Another solution, you can use Spring Shell.

```
@ShellMethod("commandName")
public String doSomething(String param) {
    return String.format("Hi %s", param);
}
```