# Java getting an error for implementing interface method with weaker access

Tags: java, interface

When I compile this code:

```
interface Rideable {
    String getGait();
}

public class Camel implements Rideable {
    int x = 2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Camel().go(8);
    }

    void go(int speed) {
        System.out.println((++speed * x++) 
        + this.getGait());
    }

    String getGait() {
        return " mph, lope";
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Camel.java:13: error: getGait() in Camel cannot implement getGait() in Rideable
String getGait() {
       ^
  attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public
1 error
```

How is the getGait method declared in the interface considered public?

Comment: methods declared in an interface are implicitly `public`. that's just how the language works. for the class that implements this interface, it must be explicitly about the access modifier of the method. in your case, `String getGait()` is `protected`, hence the error message.

Comment: This error is self-explanatory, you need to make getGait() public in class Camel.

Comment: @mre ... The getGait method actually has default visibility... package-private... not protected.

Answer (score 40):

Methods declared inside interface are implicitly `public`. And all variables declared in the interface are implicitly `public static final` (constants).

```
public String getGait() {
  return " mph, lope";
}
```

Answer (score 8):

All methods in an `interface` are implicitly `public`, regardless if you declare it explicitly or not. See more information in the [Java Tutorials Interfaces section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceDef.html).

Answer (score 7):

All methods in `interface` are implicitly `public`. But inside a class if public is not mentioned explicitly, it has only package visibility. Through overriding, you can only increase visibility. You cannot decrease visibility. So modify the implementation of `getGait()` in the class camel as

```
public String getGait() {
    return " mph, lope";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Interface fields are public, static and final by default, and the methods are public and abstract

So when you are implementing interface the function call should be **public**
Function should be

```
public String getGait() {
  return " mph, lope";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Make getGait() in Camel class (implemented class of Rideable) as public.

```
public String getGait() {
        return " mph, lope";
    }
```