# doSomething() in ClassOne can't implement doSomething() in InterfaceOne, attempt to assign weaker access privilege, was public

Tags: java, interface, subclass, superclass

`SubclassOne` extends `ClassOne` and implements `InterfaceOne`, both of which has a `void doSomething(){}` method. However, the compiler display error message,

> doSomething() in ClassOne can't implement doSomething() in
>   InterfaceOne, attempt to assign weaker access privilege, was public

Could someone please tell me why the compiler display this particular message? What is the reason behind it?

```
public class ClassOne {
    void doSomething(){
        System.out.println("do something from InterfaceMethod class");
    }
}


public interface InterfaceOne {
    default void doSomething(){
        System.out.println("do something from InterfaceOne");
    }
}


public class SubclassOne extends ClassOne implements InterfaceOne{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Methods in interfaces are implicitly `public`.

Comment: I think the question is about classone not implementing interfaceone, but still getting an error. Its not a duplicate of that

Comment: @TamasHegedus The error isn't in `ClassOne`. The message simply refers to `ClassOne` because `SubclassOne` is trying to override it. The error is in `SubclassOne` for inheriting `doSomething` as package private and trying to implement it as `public` for `InterfaceOne`. This is an exact duplicate.

Comment: @Pillar so it happens because of the default implementation in the interface is present. Interesting. I think that should be pointed out in an answer

Comment: @TamasHegedus No, this has nothing to do with `default`. If it was just a standard method declaration with no `default`, the same error would occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methods in interfaces are `public`. Methods without access modifier `package-private`, i.e. weaker access privilege. Add `public` modifier to `doSomething` in `ClassOne`

```
public class ClassOne {
    public void doSomething(){
        System.out.println("do something from InterfaceMethod class");
    }
}
```

You can see the access modifiers table at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Comment: You have enough reputation. Please just vote for the duplicate.

Comment: @Pillar I don't think its a duplicate. At least not what you marked as duplicate.

Comment: Why not? They are asking about the same thing. The most [upvoted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13160716/5191913) states the exact same things as you.

Comment: I dont think my question and the suggested possible duplicate are the same.

Comment: @Pillar in the other post the OP doesn't get the error in collision between Interface and parent class.

Comment: The effect is the same. You have one class implementing a method (whether through inheritance or directly) at package private when an interface requires it to be `public`. We don't need another question for this.

Comment: @Pillar I guess we will just agree to disagree.

Answer (score 2):

In this situation your `SubclassOne` will be going to provide an implementation which satisfies both superclass, and interface. So since there is a conflict with access modifiers of two methods, you're getting such error message.

(Your `ClassOne`'s access modifier isn't `public`. It's package visible.)