# What is happening in LocationResult?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, location

I've been searching around on how to implement a way to get a user's location in Android and I came across this SO question: 
[What is the simplest and most robust way to get the user's current location on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-a?lq=1)

My questions is, what is LocationResult? How would I use it? I am building a similar application in that question where I search for nearby places based on the current location. I  am thinking about having a separate class like that for polling location changes so I don't have to repeat the code in different activities. I suspect that LocationResult is for this purpose? Can you show me and example of how to use it in 2 activities in an OnCreate() method?

Comment: That question and its answers are nearly three years old at this point. In Android years, that's a minor eternity. You might consider reading the documentation for more up-to-date guidance: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

Comment: Did you find something?

Answer (score 0):

Johnathan,

the LocationResult is a simple way of retrieving data to handle. It's a abstract class where you can implement subclasses in order to use the data. See the [abstract class concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913098/what-is-the-difference-between-an-interface-and-abstract-class):

Answer (score 0):

That's the code You need:

```
    protected LocationCallback mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback()
{
    @Override
    public void onLocationAvailability(LocationAvailability locationAvailability) {
        super.onLocationAvailability(locationAvailability);
        if(!locationAvailability.isLocationAvailable())
        {// No location available
            checkLocationSettings();
            Snackbar snackLocationUnavailable = Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.myCoordinatorLayout), R.string.location_unavailable, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
            snackLocationUnavailable.show();
        }
        else
        {
            Snackbar snackLocationAvailable = Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.myCoordinatorLayout), R.string.location_available, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
            snackLocationAvailable.show();
        }
}

    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
        super.onLocationResult(locationResult); 
        mLastLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();
        mMyLatLng = new LatLng(valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()), valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
        meMarker.setPosition(mMyLatLng);
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mMyLatLng, 15));
        Snackbar snak2 = Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.myCoordinatorLayout), R.string.location_updated, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
        snak2.show();
    }
};
```

...

```
onCreate(){
// Build GoogleApiClient
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

//`Build LocationRequest
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(2000)        // 2 seconds, in milliseconds
                .setFastestInterval(1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds
`
//     

Build LocationSettingsRequest
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder lRbuilder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
        lRbuilder.addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
        mLocationSettingsRequest = lRbuilder.build();
        lRbuilder.setAlwaysShow(true);

// ...

LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, null);

//...

 LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationCallback);
```