# Relationship between Interfaces and Abstract Data Type in Java

Tags: java, interface, abstract-data-type

This is not about abstract class vs interfaces.

I hope someone can explain the relationship between interface and ADT in Java.
I think of an interface as a group of abstract methods. I understand that ADT focuses on what operations are possible but don't tell how they are implemented. I read that an interface specifies the operations of an ADT, but don't fully understand what this mean.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between an interface and abstract class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913098/what-is-the-difference-between-an-interface-and-abstract-class)

Comment: Oh and: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761194/interface-vs-abstract-class-general-oo?rq=1

Comment: @Scheintod An Abstract Data Type is different from an abstract class

Comment: You're right. I missed the focus of this question. (As has the other answer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Abstract Data Type is a purely theoretical entity. It´s inception precedes object orientation.

On the other side, interfaces are  concrete constructions used in Java and other OO languages to indicate the methods that a class must implement.

Something that may confuse you is that Java interfaces, are [abstract types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_type), and not [abstract data types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type).

Comment: Thanks, I'm beginning to understand this more. I'll guess there's some gray area about these definitions, but as far as I understand it, I can use interfaces to create ADTs