# Abstraction with Java in Android

Tags: java, android, refactoring, abstraction, modularity

I was studying some tutorials concerning the Java language. I was wondering if I should abstract every time that I code something, and on any type of standard and stack?

I have seen that with every Spring Services for example, we could even abstract controllers, using interfaces with EJBs on JavaEE stack etc.

I was wondering what is the aim of that? Should I do the same thing while developing with the Android SDK?

Should I abstract every class that I code?

Comment: if you are building anything new then the root should be interface or less you can use abstract class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is always a good idea to make *modular*, *reusable* components. When an app is built from the ground up with this in mind, it becomes more and more *scalable*, more and more *self-extensible*. The same components in an app get re-used as newer features are added, saving time and effort. And it becomes easier to make changes later on or identify sources of errors. Refactoring should never be afterwards, but from the beginning.

Having said that, it is not a great idea to have more and more abstractions in mobile apps just for the sake of "abstraction". The reason, of course, is that smart phones are not as powerful as servers or even desktop computers. There is a performance penalty associated with literally every class and virtual method in an Android app. There needs to be a greater balance between "abstraction" and efficiency, and the performance trade-offs become more visible on the medium and low-end devices.

From the official docs:

**1.** [**Be careful with code abstractions**](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html#Abstractions)

**2.** [**Avoid dependency injection frameworks**](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html#DependencyInjection)

**3.** [**Avoid Creating Unnecessary Objects**](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#ObjectCreation)

**4.** [**Prefer Static Over Virtual**](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#PreferStatic)

**5.** [**Avoid Internal Getters/Setters**](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#GettersSetters)

**EDIT:**

After having recently tried out [Dagger](http://square.github.io/dagger/), I have to admit that point 2 may be a bit outdated by now. What can I say ... I came to the Dagger party quite late.

Answer (score 2):

You need abstraction whenever you have a class that you do not want to implement all of its methods.  Those classes inheriting it will be forced to implement all those methods otherwise you would need to declare the subclasses as abstract as well.

In addition to that you should be aware of interface, methods of interface must not have body and the good thing is that your class can implement as much as interface as you want. Whereas, you can only inherit one abstract class. Interfaces are like contracts. Whichever class implement them need to provide body for all of their methods.

Whether you need abstract or interface or both is really depend on your design and what you want to implement. Although it is a good practice to force those classes that have common methods to implement the same interface ( if you do not know anything about body of each of the methods) or abstract ( if you know what the body of some, all or none of the methods)

Another example would be when you have abstraction or interface if you add something to them all the subclasses or classes that are implementing them need to follow those modifications, it means the could would be more easier to get modified.

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913098/what-is-the-difference-between-an-interface-and-abstract-class), [this](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com.au/2010/10/abstraction-in-java.html) and [this](http://www.onsandroid.com/2011/12/difference-between-interface-and.html) and [open/close principle](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) as well.

Answer (score 1):

This can be interpreted in many different ways. In my point of view, abstraction is used in coding as a design principle, in cases where you need an extension or many types of implementations. For eg, in Spring, a controller may have defined as an abstract class (A) and have several other types of controllers (B,C,D..) extending A. As a user of Spring framework, If you are not satisfy with the available controller implementations, still you can develop your own controller extending A. Also Spring developers too can extend / add new controllers in future releases with ease.

Answer (score 1):

## Reusability. Hands down!

If your class has a

- Repetitive code
- Non Repetitive codes for different scenarios.

Then it is a good idea to declare the class **Abstract**.

Put the repetitive code in the abstract class and create abstract methods for the code which is going to be different.

> Here is an example.

#### Register and Unregister any BroadcastReceiver

> Abstract class

```
public abstract class BaseReceiverActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

   private BroadCastReceiver receiver;
   private IntentFilter filter;

   public abstract BroadCastReceiver getReceiver();
   public abstract IntentFilter getFilter();

   @Override
   public void onStart(){
       super.onStart();
       configureReceiver()
       registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
   }

   @Override
   public void onStop(){
       super.onPause();
       unregisterReceiver(receiver);
   }

   private void registerMyReceiver(){        
       registerReceiver(receiver, filter);    
   }

   private void configureReceiver(){
        receiver = getReceiver();
        filter   = getFilter();
   }

}
```

> Implementation class:

```
public class WifiScanner extends BaseReceiverActivity{

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle sis){
        super.onCreate(sis);
        setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout);
   }

   @Override
   public BroadCastReceiver getReceiver(){
        return new YourReceiver();
   }

   @Override
   public IntentFilter getFilter(){
        return IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
   }

}
```