# How to define comparator on SortedSet<> like TreeSet<>?

Tags: java, collections, set

I want to make a lexical sorted list of strings, so i went with the basic SortedSet

```
1)  Set<String> words = new SortedSet<String>(){}
```

and realized that SortedSet is an abstract class, in which I will have to implement the comapartor method. So i went and searched on google and found out that treeSet is better and i can use its predefined comparator method.

```
2)  SortedSet<String> words = new TreeSet<String>(){}
```

When went to java docs i realized that TreeSet extends AbstractSet rather than SortedSet. **Question 1 -** Can anyone explain how the 2nd line is still working(like i am not generalizing the Set which i would normally do instead i am using two totally different Classes with no Parent child relation).
 **Question 2 -**  how to define comparator of SortedSet which will work as TreeSet. So here is the working code with TreeSet

```
SortedSet<String> words = new TreeSet<>();
    Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s1 = scanner1.nextLine();
    int a = scanner1.nextInt();
    while(s1.length()>a){
        words.add(s1.substring(0,a));
        s1 = s1.substring(a);
    }
    Iterator itr  = words.iterator();
    while(itr!= null&&itr.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(itr.next());
    }
```

Normal Input

```
welcometojava
3
```

Expected Output

```
com
eto
jav
wel
```

Edit-1
For the answer of Question 2, i am expecting something like this

```
Set<String> words = new SortedSet<String>() {
        @Override
        public Comparator<? super String> comparator() {
            return null;
        }
        ......
```

I basically want to learn, how to make a basic comparator "like" in TreeSet while using **SortedSet**? I understand that if there is natural ordering i don't need to define a new comparator.

Comment: Got the answer to first question. Now need the answer to second question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between an interface and abstract class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913098/what-is-the-difference-between-an-interface-and-abstract-class)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Answer 1**:

`TreeSet<T>` implements the `NavigableSet<T>` interface, which extends `SortedSet<T>` who also extends `Set<T>`.

The interfaces themselves doesn't actually do the sorting, the concrete class does.

So:

```
Set<String> myStrings = new TreeSet<>();
// Add a bunch of strings
// ...
for (String s : myStrings) {
 System.out.println(s);
}
```

You would still have them in sorted order.

**Answer 2**:

Firstly, for classes that already implement `Comparable<T>`, you can omit the `Comparator` for the `TreeSet`, as "Natural Ordering" is meant by using the `Comparable<T>`'s `compareTo` method.

Otherwise you can supply a `Comparator` instance to as the `TreeSet` constructor's first argument:

```
    Set<String> myStrings = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            // Define comparing logic here
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
    });
```

or use Java 8 Lambdas:

```
    Set<String> myStrings = new TreeSet<>((o1, o2) -> o1.compareTo(o2));
```

Answer (score 3):

TreeSet implements NavigableSet, which in turn extends SortedSet, which is why line 2) works. See [TreeSet Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html).

For the second part, try this:

```
SortedSet<String> ts = new TreeSet<String>(new TSComparator());

class TSComparator implements Comparator<String>{

    @Override
    public int compare(String str1, String str2) {
        return str1.compareTo(str2);
    }

}
```

Comment: I wanted to define comparator in SortedSet not TreeSet, want to extend the SortedSet Class then define the comparator over it.

Comment: SortedSet is an interface. So you will not be able to provide implementation for the Comparator interface in SortedSet. Neither will you be able to instantiate a SortedSet object. I hope this makes sense and that my statement is not tangential to your point. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question,

TreeSet also implements NavigableSet which extends SortedSet

```
public class TreeSet<E> extends AbstractSet<E> implements NavigableSet<E>, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable

public interface NavigableSet<E> extends SortedSet<E>
```

By default sort will be done based on natural ordering and the basic primitives wrappers (`Integer, Long, ...`) implements `Comparable` interface, so no need to implement the `Comparable` if the collection holds wrappers of Primitives and natural ordering is expected

But your custom class should implement Comparable if it should be ordered in `TreeSet` else `ClassCastException` will be thrown once you add the second element

Answer (score 2):

`SortedSet<T>` is not an abstract class, it is an interface.

`TreeSet<T>` does implement `SortedSet<T>`,  but not directly: the chain of inheritance goes as follows:

`Set<T>` - `SortedSet<T>` - `NavigableSet<T>`

That is why the assignment `SortedSet<String> words = new TreeSet<String>()` works: `TreeSet<T>` is a `NavigableSet<T>`, and `NavigableSet<T>` is a `SortedSet<T>`, so the assignment is legal.

When you do not supply an explicit comparator, `TreeSet<T>`'s uses natural ordering supplied by `T`'s implementation of `Comparable<T>`.