# Why "use" keyword in PHP needs to be used with Interface?

Tags: php, oop, interface, namespaces, zend-framework2

I am a self-taught programmer and I am learning Zend Framework 2 at the moment.

I always wonder why every times when I'm trying to include a certain service, they are always required me to use Interface version of it.

For example, if I'm trying to use Service Locator, I will have to include *serviceLocatorInterface* in order to use Service Locator.
Why can't I just use Service Locator class itself.

Here is from Abstract Factory class.

```
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
```

Then I would use in it this way

```
public function canCreateServiceWithName(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator, $name, $requestedName)
```

Here is another example from Zend tutorial, https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/in-depth-guide/services-and-servicemanager.html#bringing-the-service-into-the-controller

```
use Blog\Service\PostServiceInterface;
```

We include *PostServiceInterface*. Why not just PostService?

```
public function __construct(PostServiceInterface $postService)
```

We use the *PostServiceInterface* here. Why not just PostService as a Type.

I am sure this is a very simple answer that all students can answer but since i'm learning this myself so I am having a hard time understanding it.

PS. I do understand the concept of interface and inheritance. I just don't know why we include Interface this way.

Edit: After the answer I found a link that helps me understand better why people are passing interface as a type dependency instead of a concrete type.

[What is the difference between an interface and abstract class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913098/what-is-the-difference-between-an-interface-and-abstract-class)

http://kristopherwilson.com/2015/03/26/using-interfaces-effectively-in-php/

I hope those links help someone elses too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`use` creates an local alias of the used class's *full qualified name*. An class name isn't just the name of the class, it always contains the namespace, where it is defined.

If you don't use the `use` keyword to create an local alias, php assumes, the class is in the current namespace (If you don't declare an namespace in the file, this is the root namespace `\`)

A simple example

```
// the current namespace
namespace Foo;

use Test\ClassName;

class Bar {
    public function __construct(Baz $a) {
        // Baz isn't a full qualified class name (missing leading \), so
        // php assumes, Baz is inside the current namespace Foo
        // => full class name is \Foo\Baz;
    }

    public function doSomething(ClassName $a) {
        // ClassName isn't a full qualified class name, BUT there is an use
        // statement, which imported ClassName to the local file
        // => \Test\ClassName
    }

    public function doSomethingElse(\ClassName $a) {
        // ClassName IS a full qualifed class name
        // => \ClassName
    }
}
```

note, that `\ClassName` and `\Test\ClassName` are two different classes.

---

So *why use `PostServiceInterface` instead of `PostService`*

You don't have to, but it's a good practice doing so with many benefits. I.e. you want to test the function later and don't have a `PostService`. Creating an new class, which inherits from `PostService` don't might be a good solution (and even couldn't be possible, because PostService could be declared `final`)

They way out of this is: Don't use the class, use the interface as parameter. This principle is part of the [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) principles, named *[Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)* and states two things:

- *High-level modules should not depend on low-level modules. Both should depend on abstractions.*
- *Abstractions should not depend on details. Details should depend on abstractions.*

Comment: So what you are saying is namespace is a type and it's a type that you pass  to the function. What I don't understand is why are you passing Interface as a type and why don't you pass a Class as a type.

Comment: There's no difference between interface and class type

Comment: @TomKoston If you have class `A` which implements interface `B`, you use the interface as function param, because you could  switch `A` with something else (i.e mock for unit testing, etc..). That gives you more flexibility for unit testing or extending your application for future changes. You could also have used `A` as type param, but this is an unnecessary restriction

Comment: This is a SOLID principle (dependency inversion) *one should “depend upon abstractions, [not] concretions* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle

Comment: Thank you~! that explains why people are passing interface as a type dependency instead of concrete type as a dependency.